# Import XML Using Xpath for Spreadsheets saying "import internal error"

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to collect some data on a few Forbes articles using import XML and XPath. I want to pull article views on this page 
http://www.forbes.com/sites/kurtbadenhausen/2014/07/20/rory-mcilroy-is-golfs-leading-man-with-british-open-win/

I'm using this.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.forbes.com/sites/kurtbadenhausen/2014/07/20/rory-mcilroy-is-golfs-leading-man-with-british-open-win/", "//html/body/div[5]/section[1]/div[2]/hgroup/h5/span")
```

The response I keep getting is

```
Import Internal Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is not finding any element. The Forbes site is displaying another layer page before the actual content page if you have not accessed it before. Hence, Google sees this layer page instead of the article content.

Hence, you can not import this page using Google Spreadsheet.