# Importing book names from goodreads.com into Google Sheets with ImportXML gives "Import Internal Error" sometimes

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that fetches names of books from [goodreads.com](https://goodreads.com):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/" & gr_id; "//*[@id='bookTitle']")
```

where `gr_id` is a column containing ids of the books. For example when `gr_id=23848607`, it fetches from URL https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23848607 and the result is "Warheart".

The formula worked fine some time ago. I did not change anything and now I noticed it stopped working for some of the books (still working for others). Instead of the name of the book now it gives `N/A` with "Import Internal Error" hint. The ids that do not work are:

```
48332548
35906922
```

How to make it work for all books?

There were many questions posted about "Import Internal Error" problems. I tried some solutions including copying the formula to a fresh sheet, but it did not work.

**Update:** I tried the following different `XPath` formulas instead of `"//*[@id='bookTitle']"`.

```
"//h1[@id='bookTitle']"
"//h1"
```

Those different `XPath` formulas worked the same as the original `XPath` formula. They worked correctly for the same ids that the original one did and produced `N/A`s for the same ids that the original one did.

**Update:** I just re-checked and all my formulas worked correctly for all gr_ids (I had not changed anything since the time when they did not work.) May be someone knows how to prevent them from stopping working in the future.

**Update:** I re-checked once again. Of all gr_ids only this one was showing `N\A` now: `35906922`. I created an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13nyouAbdMc2zz_k33luxVe3DpMqW4OVsmFuo7y_OqbE/edit#gid=0), because my working spreadsheet contains too many unrelated details, but the problem did not appear in the example spreadsheet. I went back to my working spreadsheet and reloaded it - and the problem disappeared in my working spreadsheet too. Then I added more test data in the example spreadsheet and the following new example gr_ids showed `N\A`:

```
48213012
48213092
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I tried to make a copy of the example spreadsheet to see if it fixes the problem. The behavior in the copy example spreadsheet was identical to the original example spreadsheet - the problem only with two gr_ids specified above.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of failed formula

Comment: @player0 I made an example spreadsheet and updated my question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13nyouAbdMc2zz_k33luxVe3DpMqW4OVsmFuo7y_OqbE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMPORTXML()` seems to be unreliable. I decided not to use it, because I did not find an acceptable solution to my problem. Instead of using `IMPORTXML()` I exported my books from `goodreads.com` to `csv` file (there is such a [feature](https://www.goodreads.com/review/import) of `goodreads.com`) and then imported the `csv` file into my spreadsheet. This is not be an perfect solution, because I need to re-import every time I need to update the books, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

if you run full `IMPORTXML` on those two IDs you can see it won't return anything at all:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48213012-fathers-and-sons", "//*")
```

which means that Google Sheets can't reach the XML content for some reason (could be something similar to **https://stackoverflow.com/a/24891676/5632629**)

therefore we can try to read the source code directly with `IMPORTDATA` where we can find around 70 elements with the same information so we pick one, isolate it and remove HTML tags. then we just wrap the prior formula in `IFERROR` and force the formula to take a 2nd look if it fails first time. the result is like this:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/"&A:A, "//*[@id='bookTitle']"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/"&A:A), 100, 1), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains '</title>'"), ">(.*) by"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This fixed the example data, but when I added more data to the table, many cells would show "Loading..." forever. Even after I removed all newly added data and rebooted the computer, the "Loading..." forever problem would stay. 
25180026 https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25180026 Loading...
48850358 https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48850358 Loading...
 This is an updated example spreadsheet with formula based on IMPORTDATA() https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vuxX-IjApulJ1QvKbCt2DGY7cmnmt9HBn50vFjeL-rw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Also there is a note in the IMPORTDATA() documentation saying "A maximum of 50 IMPORTDATA calls are supported on a single spreadsheet" https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko well, of course, all import formulas are limited in amount of calls. having too many of them per spreadsheet will always lead to not executing them all